# Threads Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I start a thread when I click a button. This thread needs to do some calculations and update some stuff in the User-Interface sometimes. But when I update the ui my thread has to **wait** because it relies on a listview. How do I do that?

I thought I could do something like this (Pseudocode):

```
//On Button Click
thread.start();

//In the Thread
{
   //do calculations
   runOnUiThread( new Runnable() { /* Update Stuff */ };
   waitForUiThread(); //Wait for it to finish
   //do calculations again
   //...
}
```

Comment: @blackbelt Yeah, I start a new thread and in that thread i do some calculations. Then I have to update with these calculations my ui and wait till its done updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, use a `CountDownLatch`:

```
//In the Thread
{
   //do calculations

   CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

   runOnUiThread( new Runnable() { /* Update Stuff */ };
   countDownLatch.await(); //Wait for it to finish
   //do calculations again
   //...
}
```

In your UI, call `countDownLatch.countDown()` to trigger the thread.

Comment: ok but the `CountDownLatch` has to be shared with the UI Thread. Assuming, the thread declared as inner class of the Activity it would be a bit nicer to instantiate it in the outer scope

Answer (score 1):

Use the wait method of the thread to put it on blocked state then when the ui is fnish you can then use the notify method of the thread to go on running state.

**sample:**

```
   {
   //do calculations
   runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
   thread.await();
   /* Update Stuff */ 
   thread.notify();
   };
   //do calculations again
   //...
}
```

Comment: the Thread class has not `await` method. and wait and notify need an synchronized  block to work correctly

Comment: how would this synchronized block look like? I found something in google but it synchronizes methods or something like that